# Return of the "object references an unsaved transient instance"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I had 2 classes, `Forecast` and `Cost`, with a many-to-many relationship defined between them. We have now added an 'Order' column to the linktable (so our customers can specify an order of `Cost`s within a `Forecast`). In order to reflect this in our mapping, we created a new entity `ForecastCost` and replaced the many-to-many between `Forecast` and `Cost` by `Forecast` 1-* `ForecastCost` *-1 `Cost`.

The mappings look like this:

**Forecast.hbm.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"  namespace="FinRep" assembly="FinRep">
  <class name="Forecast" table="FORECAST" polymorphism="implicit">
    <id name="Id" column="PKFORECAST" type="long" access="field.camelcase" unsaved-value="0"><!-- ... --></id>

    <!-- ... -->

    <bag name="KostComponenten" table="FORECASTCOST" access="field.camelcase" lazy="false" cascade="save-update">
      <key column="FKFRBFORECAST"></key>
      <one-to-many class="ForecastCost" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**ForecastCost.hbm.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"  namespace="FinRep" assembly="FinRep">
    <class name="ForecastCost" table="FORECASTCOST">
        <composite-id name="ForecastCostId" class="FinRep.ForecastCostKey, FinRep">
            <key-many-to-one name="Forecast" column="FKFORECAST" lazy="false" class="FinRep.Forecast, FinRep" />
            <key-many-to-one name="Cost" column="FKCOST" lazy="false" class="FinRep.Cost, FinRep" />
        </composite-id>

        <property name="Order" column="ORDER" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

First, the 'cascade' property on the bag in the `Forecast` mapping was not set, so when I tried to save a `Forecast` that had some `Cost`s linked to it, I would (rightfully so) get an error saying the relevant `ForecastCost` objects could not be retrieved from the database. I thought adding the 'cascade' property would fix that, but now when I try to save `Forecast`#1 (for example) I get an exception saying `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing` with type=Forecast entity=1.

What I think is happening is that it tries to save the Forecase, and by doing so it also tries to persist all the `ForecastCost`/`Cost` objects linked to it, but the `ForecastCost` object also has a link back to the `Forecast` entity that we are saving (but is not yet saved, thus transient) and so it errors out.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Something I just discovered - I only get the error when using `SaveOrUpdateCopy`. When using `SaveOrUpdate` everything works OK.

Answer (score 0):

just another aproach which let you stay with the classes you had.

```
class ForeCast
{
    // public virtual ICollection<Kost> KostComponenten { get; set; } // old
    public virtual IList<Kost> KostComponenten { get; set; }          // new
}
```

and map it:

```
<list name="KostComponenten" table="FORECASTCOST" access="field.camelcase" lazy="false" cascade="save-update">
  <key column="FKFRBFORECAST"/>
  <index column="order"/>
  <many-to-many class="ForecastCost" />
</bag>
```

then the order is in the List and you can do `KostComponenten.Insert(...)`, `KostComponenten.Add(...)` and so on

Comment: That was my original plan, but I read that NHibernate will not react nicely when there's a gap in the order sequence (eg 1, 2, 4, 5) or when there are duplicates (0, 0, 0) -- things that are bound to happen and that I can easily solve when just ordering in clientside...

Comment: @efdee how do you maintain the order? if you use IList's _add_, _insert_ and _remove_ there shouldnt be 0,0,0 and gaps are just treated as null pointer in the list

Comment: First, we have alot of entries in the database already and by default their order will now be set to 0, this alone will be a problem already. Second, I don't want a delete to result in an update to all other rows (to fix their indexes). It's just not practical wrt my use case right now.

Comment: note: i have the same problem in one of my projects, i simply defined a sql-statement in my updatescript which initizes the list index column to incrementing numbers. you're right its not practical if you have update-heavy ordering of the costs in the forecast